# How can I find Dogmeat after I've made him stay in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I told Dogmeat to stay outside this raider building because even though he has armor I don't want him to die. After I came out I searched the area and I couldn't find him. I think if he's told to stay somewhere he won't show up when you fast travel and I tried one post that said to hit <kbd>~</kbd> and then type `prid0001d162` and then hit enter and then type `moveto player` and then hit <kbd>~</kbd> again to leave. But when I first typed in `prid0001d162` and hit enter it said "Script command prid0001d162" not found." What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

Dogmeat will be walking around randomly in Sanctuary Hills and will sometimes walk away from there. He will also sometimes go to other settlements you have discovered. Usually the most recent settlement you have visited when you dismiss him.